# How to point a page to a different web.config?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible for a page in ASP .NET to point to a different web.config? Example, I have 2 different config files, one is web.config and the other one is web1.config. How can I point the page to web1.config in ASP .NET?

Comment: I guess you want both pages to be hosted on the same site?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf yes

Answer (score 5):

From what I know, you cannot point a page to a different web.config file. However, you can organize your Web Site/Application into sub-folders, with one main web.config file at the root folder and a new web.config file in a sub-folder for sub-folder specific settings. You can then make a copy of this sub-folder and modify its web.config for different settings.

Instead of making a copy of the files, an idea I have is to set a virtual directory in the sub-folder so that you can reuse the same web site/application and control it with different web.config files. I have not tried this before, but I think it's worth a try!

## [Web.config Inheritance and Overrides](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides)

> Each Web.config file applies configuration settings to the directory
> that it is in and to all of the child directories below it. **Settings
> in child directories can optionally override** or modify settings that
> are specified in parent directories. Configuration settings in a
> Web.config file can optionally be applied to individual files or
> subdirectories by specifying a path in a location element.

[image: Nested Web.config files]